# Can I combine if and with statements in a single line?

Tags: python, if-statement, indentation, with-statement

I've a code block as follows:

```
if condition:
    with something as another_thing:
        // do my stuff here
```

I don't like this style due to multiple indentations. Can I combine if and with statements in a single line somehow, and reduce the indentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, but you could put multiple statements on the same line. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html).

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that while you _can_ put multiple statements on a line, but it not considered a good style by many as well as by [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations).

Comment: Can you provide a brief example if possible? I think it might not work for nested expressions.

Comment: It doesn't work for nested expressions and as martineau pointed out, you really shouldn't do it. But if you wanted to, you could something like `if x == 1: print(x); print(y);`